# Additive subgroups of the finite field GF($2^m$)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Consider the set $G=\left\{ {0,1,...,{2^m} - 1} \right\}$. The elements of this set can be viewed as the elements of GF($q=2^m$) with appropriate addition/multiplication operations. For example, GF(4) = $\left\{ {0,1,2,3} \right\}$, GF(8)=$\left\{ {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} \right\}$ with field operations defined in [GF(4)](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GF(4)), [GF(8)](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GF(8)) (where $a,b,...$ should be understood here as $2,3,...$.). Note that $2^m$ above should be understood as "regular" exponentiation (i.e., the exponent operation in $\mathcal{R}$). In particular, $G$ can be viewed as an Abelian group with the addition operation of the field.

It is clear that subgroups of $G$ must be of sizes that are a power of $2$, according to Lagrange's theorem. Define the sets ${S_j} = \left\{ {0,1,...,{2^j} - 1} \right\}$ for $j=1,2,...,m$ (again, $2^j$ is a regular exponentiation, e.g. ${S_2} = \left\{ {0,1,2,3} \right\}$). I have the following questions:

1. Can the addition operation of the field GF($q=2^m$) can always be defined such that $S_j$ are subgroups of $G$ (it is the case in the examples above)?
2. If so, $g \cdot {S_j} = \left\{ {g \cdot 0,g \cdot 1,...,g \cdot \left( {{2^j} - 1} \right)} \right\}$ for $g \in G$ is also a subgroup of $G$. is it correct to say that **all** subgroups of $G$ are of the form $g \cdot S_j$?
3. Otherwise, which subgroups exist except for $g \cdot S_j$?

Comment: No. in $GF(2^m)$ we have e.g. $2^j-1=1$, i.e. your $S_j$ is just $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Hint: this is a vector space over $GF(2)$, and a subgroup of order $2^n$ corresponds to picking $n$ independent elements. So you need to find out which ways you can pick those, and which choices give you the same groups.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Please note that $2^j$ is a regular exponentiation, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You have chosen a numbering of the elements, but you have not explained how those elements add together. Why are those subsets subgroups at all?

Comment: But you are not only looking at those two examples. You have a general one, and I don't see any pattern to those examples that make this any nicer.

Comment: One can certainly define the addition to make the first part work. But I think the second part can never happen (except for $GF(4)$) since it will  give too few subgroups of order $4$.

Comment: When you multiply elements of $\mathbb Z$ with elements of $GF(2^n)$, the only valid interpretation I can read into that is the fact that any abelian group os a $\mathbb Z$-module. In this interpretatoin, again, $2\cdot g=0$ for all $g\in GF(2^n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my comment expanded as an answer.

First, to define the addition to make all the $S_j$ subgroups, we can do the following: Write the numbers from $0$ to $2^m-1$ in binary and define the addition bitwise (mod $2$). Thus, we see that $S_j$ consists of those numbers that have $0$'s on the first (i.e. most significant) $m-j$ bits, and clearly this subset is closed under the chosen addition.

To see that not all subgroups are of the form $S_j$ when $m\geq 4$, we can simply count the number of subgroups of order $4$. A subgroup of order $4$ is determined by picking two distinct elements, but there are $3$ choices of such two elements for each subgroup. So the number of subgroups of order $4$ is $\frac{1}{3}\binom{2^m-1}{2} = \frac{(2^m-1)(2^m-2)}{6} > 2^m-1$ (since $2^m-2 > 6$). But there are only $2^m-1$ subgroups of the form $g\cdot S_2$, so these cannot be all the subgroups of order $4$ (and the other $S_j$ have different orders).

Comment: Is it possible to count the number of subgroups (of a given order, not necessarily $4$) of $G$ in this case?

Comment: @r1c Of course. The subgroups are in fact subspaces of the $n$ dimensional $GF(2)$-vector space $GF(2^n)$. To count the subgroups of order $2^k$, count the number of linearly independent families of $k$ vectors and divide by the number of bases $GF(2^k)$ has. That is $(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-4)\cdots(2^n-2^{k-1})$ divided by $(2^k-1)(2^k-2)(2^k-4)\cdots (2^k-2^{k-1})$.

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there any simple way to find these subgroups rather than by checking subsets of size $2^k$ containing $0$ for closure?